# Simple Java Stack Addition

Tags: java, stack

Here is my code

```
package practice;

import java.util.Stack;

public class prac {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int K = -1;
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter the amount of positive numbers to add up: ");
            K = In.getInt();
        } while(K<0);
        int i;
        Stack sum = new Stack();
        int number;
        int totalsum;
        System.out.println("Enter " + K + " values between 1 and 100, or a 0 to to ignore the last number submitted");
        for(i = 1; i <= K; i++){
            number = In.getInt();
            if(number == 0)
                sum.pop();
            else
            sum.push(number);

            System.out.print(sum);
        }

    }
}
```

Very new to java. Just need to know the SIMPLEST and EASIEST way to add all the values in the stack together. ie. If the stack was [1, 2, 3] the answer would be 6

Comment: you would need to add the logic in your if statement, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I would declare a variable named `total`
and in your `if(number== 0)` statement:

```
while(!sum.isEmpty()){
  total += sum.pop();
}
```

You should also modify your print statement to print the value of `total`